# Populate cell with x-number of letters based on another cell's value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spread sheet for a game I am creating. In this, there are different skills with a corresponding level. Next to this, I have a number of boxes that I want the players to tick off. The number of boxes correspond to the level of the skill. So its a really simple set up.
My question is, can I have Excel populate the cell with the boxes automatically based on the number in the cell next to it (see the hard coded example below).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DE2K.png)

So, for example, I want to put a 5 in C5 and in D5 automatically populates 5x"q"'s or qqqqq (font is windings, which gives me the boxes).
In lay-mans terms, I want a formula in cell D5 = REPCHAR($C5, "q") to then generate the string "qqqqq" in D5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `REPT(text, num_times)` function.

For your example, D5 would be `=REPT("☐", C5)`

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rept-function-04c4d778-e712-43b4-9c15-d656582bb061

Comment: ah great! learned something new today! thank you.  :)